# How to use Dotfuscator with VSTO?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel, vsto, dotfuscator

Right now, I use Dotfuscator in my all c# programs,but ,if I use it in VSTO, when I try to deploy in target computer, VSTO always prompt me: "File has a different computed hash than specified in manifest"

My question is, How to use Dotfuscator with VSTO in right way?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to perform the obfuscation right after the assemblies are compiled/built - this will ensure that the new obfuscated assemblies are used to compute hashes/manifests etc.

Not sure if Dotfuscator supports this, but [Crypto Obfuscator](http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm) does - Crypto Obfuscator has a wizard which you run on your VS project and then obfuscation will be automatically performed everytime, and immediately after, your project is built.

Answer (score 0):

I used Dotfuscator for VSTO and it worked well.

An example is here:
https://www.preemptive.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/WordAddIn.zip

You need to add the following lines to the end of csproj file before closing `</Project>` tag:

```
  <!-- Import environment-specific build properties for Dotfuscator, if they exist. -->
  <Import Project="$([System.Environment]::GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.UserProfile))/.dotfuscator.user.props" Condition="Exists('$([System.Environment]::GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.UserProfile))/.dotfuscator.user.props')" />
  <!-- Set build properties for Dotfuscator. -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Specify the location of the MSBuild targets, if not already provided. -->
    <DotfuscatorMSBuildDir Condition="'$(DotfuscatorMSBuildDir)' == ''">$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)/MSBuild/PreEmptive/Dotfuscator/6</DotfuscatorMSBuildDir>
    <!-- Generate a default Dotfuscator config file (DotfuscatorConfig.xml) if it doesn't exist. -->
    <!-- TODO: Set this to false after the file is generated by the first local build. -->
    <DotfuscatorGenerateConfigFileIfMissing>true</DotfuscatorGenerateConfigFileIfMissing>
    <!-- Enable Dotfuscator for Release builds. -->
    <DotfuscatorEnabled Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">true</DotfuscatorEnabled>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <!-- Import the Dotfuscator MSBuild targets. Must be done last. -->
  <Import Project="$(DotfuscatorMSBuildDir)/PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Common.targets" />
```